Grid search when using PYOD module
I am practicing unsupervised learning using the pyod module and I want to compare the performance of different algorithms using GridSearch. However, when I try to determine the best score, I always get nan values for each model:
models = {
'ABOD': ABOD(),
'CBLOF': CBLOF(),
'FeatureBagging': FeatureBagging(),
'HBOS': HBOS(),
'IForest': IForest(),
'KNN': KNN(),
'LOF': LOF()
}

params = {
'ABOD': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        'n_neighbors': [5, 10, 20]},
'CBLOF': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        'check_estimator': [True, False]},
'FeatureBagging': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        'check_estimator': [True, False]},
'HBOS': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]},
'IForest': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]},
'KNN': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]},
'LOF': {'contamination': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
        'n_neighbors': [5, 10, 20]}
}
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from tqdm import tqdm



best_estimators = {}
best_scores = {}
for model_name in models.keys():
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(models[model_name],                    
        params[model_name], scoring='roc_auc', cv=5)
    grid_search.fit(X)
    best_estimators[model_name] = grid_search.best_estimator_
    best_scores[model_name] = grid_search.best_score_
    print(f"Best parameters for {model_name}: 
              {grid_search.best_params_}")
    print(f"Best score for {model_name}: {grid_search.best_score_}")


are you sure that pyod model objects are compatible with scikit-learn gridsearch?

@rehaqds They are not compatible. I want to find a way to quantify the best model amongst the ones I was using from the PYOD module and since I was focusing on unsupervised learning, I found using the silhouette score to be the best way
